# set tomcat path

Tags: tomcat, path, java-home

I'm facing a problem in setting the path of tomcat. I used a batch file to 
set the path, which is

```
cd\

set JAVA_HOME=C:\Sun\SDK\jdk

set CATALINA_HOME=c:\Tomcat5.5

set PATH=%CATALINA_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%path%
set CLASSPATH=.;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%CATALINA_HOME%\common\lib\servlet-api.jar;

cd %CATALINA_HOME%\webapps
start
```

Initially it was working, but now it's not working.

Comment: I see no problem except your last line "cd %CATALINA_HOME%\webapps start"
Are you looking into webapps or bin

Comment: but previously it was working fine.

Comment: @Ryan why are you trying to run start inside the webapps dir ? Try the bin/ directory.

Comment: @nos sorry to reply late but i asked this question long ago i was a learner at that time.... any way thanks for your comment..

Answer (score 1):

You only need to set the JAVA_HOME and CATALINA_HOME variables. You don't need to set the CLASSPATH (and you probably shouldn't), catalina.bat will set it properly . I recommend to use a script like the following:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Sun\SDK\jdk
set CATALINA_HOME=c:\Tomcat5.5
"%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\startup.bat"
```

The above assumes that you've downloaded the zip version of Tomcat.